# How to make a Whatsapp chat Bubble with react-native gifted chat

Tags: reactjs, react-native, user-interface, whatsapp, react-native-gifted-chat

How can I create a message Bubble like a Whatsapp Bubble? Time must be at the same line for a single line message otherwise below it.
The bubble should have a minimum width and message text should be flex-start and time would be flex-end.

I tried to restyle the Bubble and Time component but only achieved this much so far.[image: Current Bubbles]

Expected Result
[image: Expected Bubbles]